# How to bind the model to a list of checkboxes in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I need some help for **proper binding the model to a list of checkboxes** (Mon-Sun).

**Any help is appreciated. Thanks.**

[image]

**SERVER Model**

```
public class DailySchedule : ReportSchedule
{
    public string Option { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, bool> RunOnDays { get; set; }
}
```

**JSON Data** I receive from server comes in this format:

```
vm.reportSchedule
{
  "Option": "EveryWeekday",
  "RunOnDays": {
    "Mon": true,
    "Tue": true,
    "Wed": true,
    "Thu": true,
    "Fri": true,
    "Sat": false,
    "Sun": false
  }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="checkbox" name="dailyOption" ng-model="vm.reportSchedule.RunOnDays" value="Mon">Mon
    <input type="checkbox" name="dailyOption" ng-model="vm.reportSchedule.RunOnDays" value="Tue">Tue
    <input type="checkbox" name="dailyOption" ng-model="vm.reportSchedule.RunOnDays" value="Wed">Wed
    <input type="checkbox" name="dailyOption" ng-model="vm.reportSchedule.RunOnDays" value="Thu">Thu
    <input type="checkbox" name="dailyOption" ng-model="vm.reportSchedule.RunOnDays" value="Fri">Fri
    <input type="checkbox" name="dailyOption" ng-model="vm.reportSchedule.RunOnDays" value="Sat">Sat
    <input type="checkbox" name="dailyOption" ng-model="vm.reportSchedule.RunOnDays" value="Sun">Sun
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an `ngRepeat` with the key/val syntax:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input ng-repeat="(day, bool) in vm.reportSchedule.RunOnDays" type="checkbox" name="dailyOption" ng-model="vm.reportSchedule.RunOnDays[day]" />{{day}}
</div>
```